# How to get rid of auto generated classes in secondary menu links and add my own classes

Tags: routes

I have taken the standard code for secondary menu from a Drupal 7 theme:

```
 <?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
            <?php print $search_form; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($search_form): ?>
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav'),
              ),
              'heading' => array(
                'text' => t('secondary'),
                'level' => 'h2',
                'class' => array('element-invisible'),
                  ),
                    )); ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
```

Now the ht,l output generates some autogen css witch i whant to get rit of and replace with my own classes?

```
<h2 class="element-invisible">secondary</h2>

<ul id="secondary-menu-links" class="menu nav navbar-nav">
<li class="menu-3 first"><a href="/user">My account</a></li>
<li class="menu-15 last"><a href="/user/logout">Log out</a></li>
</ul>                                  
</div>
```

How to delete menu-3 and menu-15 as well as all classes following when we add more links and add some custom links to work with stuff like font awesome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this preprocess hook to modify the menu classes.

For example, modify the output of the secondary menu links like this.

```
function YOURTHEME_links__system_secondary_menu(&$variables)
{
   $output = "";

   foreach ($variables['links'] as $item => $link) {
      $classes = array('class1', 'class2');
      $output .= sprintf('<li class="%s">%s</li>', implode(' ', $classes), l($link['title'], $link['href']));
   }

   return $output;
}
```